# How do you update a provisioning profile after adding more people?

Tags: ios, xcode5, ios-provisioning

I can't figure out how to get Xcode to update my provisioning profile after adding more users/devices.

Say I have profile A with people a,b,c in it, and then I add d,e to profile A, how do get them to show with the profile I'm using to create an adhoc build from organizer.

I've tried:

File -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Details and hitting the 'refresh' button on the page of signing identifies and provisioning profiles.

When creating the adhoc build, on the Dropdown list I've tried 'refresh code signing identity...' with no avail.

Thankfully I can update the profile manually via TestFlight, but I'd prefer not to do this, and feel like there is something obvious I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this process...

In your Developer Account (developer.apple.com)

1. Log in
2. Select the Member Centre
3. Select the section titled Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles
4. Under the section titled iOS Apps, select Devices
5. Check that the new user's device is included in the list.

In Xcode:

1. Select the menu item Xcode > Preferences
2. Select the Preferences tab > Accounts
3. Against your Apple ID used for development, select the button View Details
4. In the Account Details pop-up window, select the refresh icon in the bottom left corner

Your provisioning profiles should be updated, however I have found in the past that this process sometimes does not complete immediately ( a matter of 5 to 15 minutes).

Comment: Thank you.  This was the process I was attempting to use, but expecting immediate results.  I'll give this a shot.